# Android NestedScrollView scrolling to the wrong position

Tags: android, nestedscrollview

I Have a `NestedScrollView` which it has some elements like `textView`,`recyclerView` etc. in itself .

The Problem is When i call smoothScrollTo(x,y) for first time , everything is OK .

But second call of smoothScrollTo(x,y) will change the scroll position again in a random position.

Here is the code :

```
public void linkToComments(View view) {
     int[] pos = {0, 0};
     commentsCountText.getLocationOnScreen(pos);
     scrollView.fling(0);
     scrollView.smoothScrollTo(pos[0], pos[1]);
}
```

whats the problem ?

Comment: Found any solution ? Having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may solve your problem

```
 public void linkToComments(View view) {
    scrollView.fling(0);
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, commentsCountText.getBottom());
}
```

Comment: no difference  , i think there is a problem in getting element position